# What is the difference between these two arrays and why does typeahead w/ autoform only work with one of them?

Tags: meteor, underscore.js, typeahead.js, meteor-autoform

Here is my SimpleSchema:

```js
confirmedAddress: {
    //addressRecordID
    type: String,
    label: "Address",
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        type: "typeahead",
        /*
        options: function() {
            return [{
                label: "2013",
                value: 2013
            }, {
                label: "2014",
                value: 2014
            }, {
                label: "2015",
                value: 2015
            }]
        }
        */
        options: function() {
            var addresses = Addresses.find({
                houseNumber: "0"
            }).map(function(address) {
                return {
                    label: address.houseNumber + " " + address.street + ", " + address.unit + ", " + address.city,
                    value: address._id
                };
            });
            /*console.log("addresses",addresses)*/
            var addresses2 = [{
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "rec2I5yyHm6rSQOAO"
            }, {
                "label": "0 unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recBEYzyvjfCm0D4k"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recFdDsCzYgXGWWyC"
            }, {
                "label": "0 SE Muskogee Ave, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recH0g6UvLrztSCCR"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recK8aT6gQoRsqDVP"
            }, {
                "label": "0 unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recKstPZAt5wrGzRT"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recSf7X7LLIWqvvGK"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recbUExSc2Rd1kFSp"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Oak, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recekb3FlD6vghcf0"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "rechiCWJ9ScAeBOC4"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "reclUGe2NkeLSafWj"
            }, {
                "label": "0 unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "reclsD03UdhBwLc6b"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Moved out of territory, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recrLqh76Qk7EHQcm"
            }, {
                "label": "0 Unknown, undefined, undefined",
                "value": "recyyDLXMkHMRf9bn"
            }]
            console.log(addresses, addresses2)
            console.log("addresses == addresses2", addresses == addresses2) // false
            return addresses2
        }
    }
}
```

The first commented section works fine. Returning `addresses2` works fine too. But, when I return `addresses`, typeahead doesn't work.

The thing is, I got `addresses2` by pasting this into the console and then copying it into the code:

```js
Addresses.find({
    houseNumber: "0"
}).map(function(address) {
    return {
        label: address.houseNumber + " " + address.street + ", " + address.unit + ", " + address.city,
        value: address._id
    };
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `addresses == addresses2` theyre not reference equal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the html form is created `addresses` is an empty array since it is being created. `addresses2` is hardcoded, so it is immediately available to use.